# "Error(s) encountered" While Using ldapscripts

Tags: linux, debian, ldap, openldap, debian-stretch

Below, I show my OpenLDAP configuration. This is a fresh OpenLDAP installation on a fresh Debian Stretch installation.

I am unable to use ldapscripts. Regardless what I do, I get the errors shown at the end of the text below.

```
root@my-host:~# ldapsearch -b 'dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com' -x
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# test.mydomain.com
dn: dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: test.mydomain.com
dc: test

# admin, test.mydomain.com
dn: cn=admin,dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 3
# numEntries: 2
```

/etc/ldap/ldap.conf

```
root@my-host:~# cat /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

#BASE   dc=example,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666

BASE    dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com
URI     ldap://localhost

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

/etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.conf

```
root@my-host:~# cat /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.conf
#  Copyright (C) 2005 Gana▒l LAPLANCHE - Linagora
#  Copyright (C) 2006-2016 Gana▒l LAPLANCHE
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307,
#  USA.

# Note for Debian users:
# On Debian system ldapscripts will try to parse and use nslcd config.
# Look on commented variables and description lines started with DEBIAN.
# But you could override it's values here.


# LDAP server
# DEBIAN: value from /etc/nslcd.conf (uri) is used.
SERVER="ldap://localhost"

# Suffixes
# DEBIAN: values from /etc/nslcd.conf (base maps) are used.
SUFFIX="dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com" # Global suffix
GSUFFIX="ou=Groups"        # Groups ou (just under $SUFFIX)
USUFFIX="ou=Users"         # Users ou (just under $SUFFIX)
MSUFFIX="ou=Machines"      # Machines ou (just under $SUFFIX)

# Authentication type
# DEBIAN: value from /etc/nslcd.conf (sasl_mech) is used.
# If empty, use simple authentication
# Else, use the value as an SASL authentication mechanism
SASLAUTH=""
#SASLAUTH="GSSAPI"

# Simple authentication parameters
# The following BIND* parameters are ignored if SASLAUTH is set
BINDDN="cn=admin,dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
# The following file contains the raw password of the BINDDN
# Create it with something like : echo -n 'secret' > $BINDPWDFILE
# WARNING !!!! Be careful not to make this file world-readable
BINDPWDFILE="/etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd"
# For older versions of OpenLDAP, it is still possible to use
# unsecure command-line passwords by defining the following option
# AND commenting the previous one (BINDPWDFILE takes precedence)
#BINDPWD="secret"

# Start with these IDs *if no entry found in LDAP*
GIDSTART="10000" # Group ID
UIDSTART="10000" # User ID
MIDSTART="20000" # Machine ID

# Group membership management
# ObjectCLass used for groups
# Possible values : posixGroup, groupOfNames, groupOfUniqueNames (case-sensitive !)
# Warning : when using groupOf*, be sure to be compliant with RFC 2307bis (AUXILIARY posixGroup).
# Also, do not mix posixGroup and groupOf* entries up in you directory as, within RFC 2307bis,
# the former is a subset of the latter. The ldapscripts wouldn't cope well with this configuration.
GCLASS="posixGroup"   # Leave "posixGroup" here if not sure !
# When using  groupOfNames or groupOfUniqueNames, creating a group requires an initial
# member. Specify it below, you will be able to remove it once groups are populated.
#GDUMMYMEMBER="uid=dummy,$USUFFIX,$SUFFIX"

# User properties
# DEBIAN: values from /etc/adduser.conf are used.
USHELL="/bin/bash"
#UHOMES="/home/%u"     # You may use %u for username here
CREATEHOMES="no"      # Create home directories and set rights ?
#HOMESKEL="/etc/skel"  # Directory where the skeleton files are located. Ignored if undefined or nonexistant.
#HOMEPERMS="755"       # Default permissions for home directories

# User passwords generation
# Command-line used to generate a password for added users.
# You may use %u for username here ; special value "<ask>" will ask for a password interactively
# WARNING    !!!! This is evaluated, everything specified here will be run !
# WARNING(2) !!!! Some systems (Linux) use a blocking /dev/random (waiting for enough entropy).
#                 In this case, consider using /dev/urandom instead.
#PASSWORDGEN="cat /dev/random | LC_ALL=C tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | head -c8"
#PASSWORDGEN="pwgen"
#PASSWORDGEN="echo changeme"
#PASSWORDGEN="echo %u"
#PASSWORDGEN="<ask>"
PASSWORDGEN="pwgen"

# User passwords recording
# you can keep trace of generated passwords setting PASSWORDFILE and RECORDPASSWORDS
# (useful when performing a massive creation / net rpc vampire)
# WARNING !!!! DO NOT FORGET TO DELETE THE GENERATED FILE WHEN DONE !
# WARNING !!!! DO NOT FORGET TO TURN OFF RECORDING WHEN DONE !
RECORDPASSWORDS="no"
PASSWORDFILE="/var/log/ldapscripts_passwd.log"

# Where to log : local file and/or syslog
LOGTOFILE="yes"
LOGFILE="/var/log/ldapscripts.log"
LOGTOSYSLOG="no"
SYSLOGFACILITY="local4"
SYSLOGLEVEL="info"

# Temporary folder
#TMPDIR="/tmp"

# Various binaries used within the scripts
# Warning : they also use uuencode, date, grep, sed, cut, which...
# Please check they are installed before using these scripts
# Note that many of them should come with your OS

# OpenLDAP client commands
LDAPSEARCHBIN="/usr/bin/ldapsearch"
LDAPADDBIN="/usr/bin/ldapadd"
LDAPDELETEBIN="/usr/bin/ldapdelete"
LDAPMODIFYBIN="/usr/bin/ldapmodify"
LDAPMODRDNBIN="/usr/bin/ldapmodrdn"
LDAPPASSWDBIN="/usr/bin/ldappasswd"

# OpenLDAP client common additional options
# This allows for adding more configuration options to the OpenLDAP clients, e.g. '-ZZ' to enforce TLS
#LDAPBINOPTS="-ZZ"

# OpenLDAP ldapsearch-specific additional options
# The following option disables long-line wrapping (which makes the scripts bug
# when handling long lines). The option was introduced in OpenLDAP 2.4.24, so
# comment it if you are using OpenLDAP < 2.4.24.
LDAPSEARCHOPTS="-o ldif-wrap=no"
# And here is an example to activate paged results
#LDAPSEARCHOPTS="-E pr=500/noprompt"

# Character set conversion : $ICONVCHAR <-> UTF-8
# Comment ICONVBIN to disable UTF-8 conversion
#ICONVBIN="/usr/bin/iconv"
#ICONVCHAR="ISO-8859-15"

# Base64 decoding
# Comment UUDECODEBIN to disable Base64 decoding
#UUDECODEBIN="/usr/bin/uudecode"

# Getent command to use - choose the ones used
# on your system. Leave blank or comment for auto-guess.
# GNU/Linux
#GETENTPWCMD="getent passwd"
#GETENTGRCMD="getent group"
# FreeBSD
#GETENTPWCMD="pw usershow"
#GETENTGRCMD="pw groupshow"
# Auto
GETENTPWCMD=""
GETENTGRCMD=""

# You can specify custom LDIF templates here
# Leave empty to use default templates
# See *.template.sample for default templates
#GTEMPLATE="/path/to/ldapaddgroup.template"
#UTEMPLATE="/path/to/ldapadduser.template"
#MTEMPLATE="/path/to/ldapaddmachine.template"
GTEMPLATE=""
UTEMPLATE=""
MTEMPLATE=""
```

/etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd

```
root@my-host:/etc/ldapscripts# cat ldapscripts.passwd
secret
```

/etc/nslcd.conf

```
root@my-host:/etc# cat nslcd.conf
# /etc/nslcd.conf
# nslcd configuration file. See nslcd.conf(5)
# for details.

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid nslcd

# The location at which the LDAP server(s) should be reachable.
uri ldap://localhost

# The search base that will be used for all queries.
base dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com

# The LDAP protocol version to use.
#ldap_version 3

# The DN to bind with for normal lookups.
binddn cn=annonymous,dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com
#bindpw secret

# The DN used for password modifications by root.
rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=test,dc=mydomain,dc=com

# SSL options
#ssl off
#tls_reqcert never
tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# The search scope.
#scope sub
```

/etc/nscd.conf

```
root@my-host:/etc# cat /etc/nscd.conf
#
# /etc/nscd.conf
#
# An example Name Service Cache config file.  This file is needed by nscd.
#
# Legal entries are:
#
#       logfile                 <file>
#       debug-level             <level>
#       threads                 <initial #threads to use>
#       max-threads             <maximum #threads to use>
#       server-user             <user to run server as instead of root>
#               server-user is ignored if nscd is started with -S parameters
#       stat-user               <user who is allowed to request statistics>
#       reload-count            unlimited|<number>
#       paranoia                <yes|no>
#       restart-interval        <time in seconds>
#
#       enable-cache            <service> <yes|no>
#       positive-time-to-live   <service> <time in seconds>
#       negative-time-to-live   <service> <time in seconds>
#       suggested-size          <service> <prime number>
#       check-files             <service> <yes|no>
#       persistent              <service> <yes|no>
#       shared                  <service> <yes|no>
#       max-db-size             <service> <number bytes>
#       auto-propagate          <service> <yes|no>
#
# Currently supported cache names (services): passwd, group, hosts, services
#


#       logfile                 /var/log/nscd.log
#       threads                 4
#       max-threads             32
#       server-user             nobody
#       stat-user               somebody
        debug-level             0
#       reload-count            5
        paranoia                no
#       restart-interval        3600

        enable-cache            passwd          no
        positive-time-to-live   passwd          600
        negative-time-to-live   passwd          20
        suggested-size          passwd          211
        check-files             passwd          yes
        persistent              passwd          yes
        shared                  passwd          yes
        max-db-size             passwd          33554432
        auto-propagate          passwd          yes

        enable-cache            group           no
        positive-time-to-live   group           3600
        negative-time-to-live   group           60
        suggested-size          group           211
        check-files             group           yes
        persistent              group           yes
        shared                  group           yes
        max-db-size             group           33554432
        auto-propagate          group           yes

        enable-cache            hosts           no
        positive-time-to-live   hosts           3600
        negative-time-to-live   hosts           20
        suggested-size          hosts           211
        check-files             hosts           yes
        persistent              hosts           yes
        shared                  hosts           yes
        max-db-size             hosts           33554432

        enable-cache            services        no
        positive-time-to-live   services        28800
        negative-time-to-live   services        20
        suggested-size          services        211
        check-files             services        yes
        persistent              services        yes
        shared                  services        yes
        max-db-size             services        33554432

        enable-cache            netgroup        no
        positive-time-to-live   netgroup        28800
        negative-time-to-live   netgroup        20
        suggested-size          netgroup        211
        check-files             netgroup        yes
        persistent              netgroup        yes
        shared                  netgroup        yes
        max-db-size             netgroup        33554432
```

And finally, the resulting errors...

```
root@my-host:~# ldapinit -s
Error(s) encountered while creating regular OUs
Error(s) encountered during LDAP initialization
root@my-host:~#
root@my-host:~#
root@my-host:~#
root@my-host:~# ldapinit
Error(s) encountered while creating root DN
Error(s) encountered while creating regular OUs
Error(s) encountered during LDAP initialization
root@my-host:/etc# ldapaddgroup test-user 7000
Error adding group test-user to LDAP
```

/var/log/ldapscripts.log does show a complaint about "invalid credentials". However, this happens whether I put my actual cn=admin password in /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd or whether I put the word "secret" in there.

/var/log/ldapscripts.log

```
root@my-host:/var/log# cat ldapscripts.log
Feb 06 11:58:07 inf-3 ldapscripts: ldapinit(my-username): /usr/sbin/ldapinit
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
  -> Error(s) encountered while creating root DN
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
  -> Error(s) encountered while creating regular OUs
  -> Error(s) encountered during LDAP initialization
Feb 06 15:03:47 inf-3 ldapscripts: ldapaddgroup(my-username): /usr/sbin/ldapaddgroup test-user 7000
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
  -> Error adding group test-user to LDAP
```

Notice the appearance of my username (my-username) in the above log output. This is in spite of the fact that I ran all OpenLDAP commands after **su -l root**.

What step am I missing to successfully use ldapscripts?

Comment: Noticed the downvote. What additional information is required to make my post useful and answerable? I will gladly provide it. Just really kind of stuck here in an area I'm very new too.

Answer (score 3):

Had a similar issue i.e. same error: *ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)*

and the only way to solve it was to delete the ldapscripts.passwd and use

```
# echo -n "mypassword" > /etc/ldapscripts/ldapscripts.passwd
```

(before I edited the file directly with vi entering the password). HTH.